# Prove that if $K\triangleleft G$ and $K\le \Phi(G)$, then every Sylow subgroup of $K$ is normal in $G$.

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Prove that if $K\triangleleft G$ and $K\le \Phi(G)\\$, then every Sylow subgroup of $K$ is normal in $G$.

$\Phi(G)$ denotes the [Frattini subgroup](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Frattini_subgroup).

---

Let $H$ be a Sylow p-subgroup of $K$. By the [Frattini's argument](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Frattini%27s_argument), element in $G$ can be write as $g=kx$, where $k\in K$, $xH=Hx$. I need to prove $g^{-1}Hg\subseteq G$ for $g\in G$. $$g^{-1}Hg=x^{-1}k^{-1}Hkx=x^{-1}k^{-1}xHx^{-1}kx=k'^{-1}Hk',$$ for some $k'\in K$. So how to use $K\le \Phi(G)$ to prove $k'^{-1}Hk'\subseteq H$?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have proved that $G = KN_G(H)$. But $K \le \Phi(G)$, so $G = \Phi(G)N_G(H)$. Now, by the non-generator property of $\Phi(G)$, this implies that $G=N_G(H)$ That is $H \unlhd G$.

Comment: That is beautiful. Thank you!